# Excel 2010 - Count Unique values only in a SUBTOTAL cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, subtotal

**Info:**  Excel 2010 (no macros)
**Data Origns:** MySQL Query / phpMyAdmin **Server:**  Apache
**Code is run via:** Server SQL Query (copy & paste in the phpMyAdmin) or in MySQL Workbench or using a custom shopping cart manager.
**Exports to:** Excel (.csv then to .xlsx for sales reports)
**Notes:** The workbook uses my Query as well as other data

**Question**
I have 2 formulas.  1 that works, 1 that is close but ultimately wrong.
1)  Gets the total of Unique OrderIDs (in my case 2342 of them) however it won't reduce to a 'SUBTOTAL' when I filter my data.
`=SUMPRODUCT((A8:A30001<>"")/COUNTIF(A8:A30001,A8:A30001&""))`

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(A8:A10001)>0,MATCH(A8:A10001,A8:A10001,0),""), IF(LEN(A8:A10001)>0,MATCH(A8:A10001,A8:A10001,0),""))>0,1))`  (SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER)

2) Returns as `SUBTOTAL` however the count is out by 1 (Returns 8, not 7):
`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A7,ROW(A7:A10000)-ROW(A7),,1)), IF(A7:A10000<>"",MATCH("~"&A7:A10000,A7:A10000&"",0))),ROW(A7:A10000)-ROW(A7)+1),1))`   (SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER)

`=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,  OFFSET(A7:A10000,  MATCH(ROW(A7:A10000),  ROW(A7:A10000))-1,  0,  1)), COUNTIF(A7:A10000, "<"&A7:A10000), ""), COUNTIF(A7:A10000, "<"&A7:A10000))>0))`    (SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER)

**Data**
This has been filtered: Month of Order, Products ID = 7 Units

```
OrdID   ProdName    Qty
2525    test            1
2538    test            1
2553    test            1
2555    test            1
2556    test            1
2564    test            1
2566    test            1
```

Thanks in advance for your insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect formula in `2)` to work OK, are you sure the discrepancy in results isn't caused by different ranges - your first formula starts at row 8 and the second at row 7? Are you including the header row in the data hence 8 as the result rather than 7?

If order Ids in column A are numeric then this version should also work

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A7,ROW(A7:A10000)-ROW(A7),,1)),A7:A10000),A7:A10000),1))`

Comment: so I feel like a stuffed turkey.  I've been staring at EXCEL & SQL for over 12 hours, I didn't even see that!  Thank you very much and have chosen the `formula` you gave as an example!  (I need sleep I think! LOL)  Thank you, have a fab day!