# Count values for each row with a unique ID

Tags: excel

I have a bunch of rows in a table. Each row reflects an event in a patient. However, one patient can have experienced multiple events, so it's possible for there to be multiple rows with the same patient number. Now I'd like to count the amount of male patients in my database, without counting the ones that had multiple events multiple times. Each patient is identified by a unique patient ID that could be used for this.

This shouldn't be all that complicated if not for the fact that I'm using a table that also has several filters, so I need to use `SUBTOTAL` for any counting functions.

I literally have no idea where to start, so I can't really provide any code...
Any function that could point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

~Laurens

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883272/excel-2010-count-unique-values-only-in-a-subtotal-cell

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of unique IDs in the same column, if the IDs are numeric, you can use `SUM` with `FREQUENCY`:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY($A$1:$A$1000,$A$1:$A$1000)>0,1))
```

If they're text and numbers mixed, you can get unique IDs with this one:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH($A$1:$A$1000,$A$1:$A$1000,0),MATCH($A$1:$A$1000,$A$1:$A$1000,0))>0,1))
```

(From [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273))

Answer (score 0):

Use a **Pivot Table** to filter and count all your patients database. Select your data and select Insert -> Tables -> Pivot Tables. Put your filters at the Filter section of the table and the Patient ID in the Rows section. Then, you can use COUNT to get the number of patients.
For more information about Pivot Tables, you can check this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Answer (score 0):

[Here you go](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TCb5x85gha-lwEAPvoKuWBBDqSTTTRgoVW50O8_DgRM/edit?usp=sharing)
[image: Formulas]

You've not mentioned whether an event is optional.
You might want to add extra column H with formula like h2=if(c2="",0,1) with 1/0 and multiply it as well in G.
Basically if column G contains a 1 you include it

Here's what the results of the formula look like:
[image: Results from formulae]

**Revision**

Table is sorted by Patient id..

on change of patient id column H contains a 1, it'll be 0 otherwise.

So H2 is hard coded to 1, H3,H4,H6 will evaluate to 1.

So now G2=H2*E2 etc. You can filter by column H. 
The beauty of mapping things into binary zeros and ones is you can do multiplication to achieve a logical AND result, whilst at the same time breaking a complex task into a series of steps. You can then apply a filter to the data to get the rows where column G are not zero, and see the totals count. Normally I'd insert a column between header and data on row 2 and then have G2=SUM(G3:G9)
Sum column H for number of patients.
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing here, but if I look at the result, it isn't what I'd want, because I want to include every patient once, regardless of the event, I just need to be able to get average age, and amount of male patients, from a database of events (and not patients).

Comment: If I just include the patients that have a 1 in column G, only patient 1 would be included, whereas I want to get: there are 2 males and 2 females.

Comment: So " without counting the ones that had multiple events multiple times" wasn't the right wording... Will post second link in a sec

Comment: Well, it kindof was... The table is a table of events. Say I have 10 events, that means I have 10 rows in my table. These events however occured in only 5 patients (each patient had 2 events, for the sake of this example), but every row contains the data of those patients (i.e. male or female). So if I do a count of all males, I get double the amount of males because it counts all the events as if they were separate patients, while they are not. So I need to do a count of several variables in my table, ignoring values of the patient ID is the same as the row above (or below)...