# How to count unique values ​in Excel while respecting filters?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to use VBA with Excel to write a formula in a cell that counts the unique values ​​of a column and works even if the column is filtered. This means that only all visible, unique values should be counted. I've researched for a long time and tried a lot, but nothing works so far.

The best solution so far (but filtering does not work):

```
cell.Formula = ”=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(” & TARGET_COLUMN_RANGE_ADDRESS & ”,” & TARGET_COLUMN_RANGE_ADDRESS & ”))”
```

Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I found a solution now:

```vb
' The letter of the target columns address
Dim columnLetter As String
columnLetter = Split(columnRange.Address, "$")(1)

' columnRange: The range of the target column.
' columnNamesRowNumber: Just a number to adjust the row number because of the table starts not at the first row.
cell.Formula = "=SUM((FREQUENCY(SUBTOTAL(3, INDIRECT(""" & columnLetter & """ & ROW(" & columnRange.row & ":" & columnNamesRowNumber + columnRange.Rows.Count + 1 & "))) * (" & columnLetter & columnRange.row & ":" & columnLetter & columnNamesRowNumber + columnRange.Rows.Count + 1 & "), SUBTOTAL(3, INDIRECT(""" & columnLetter & """ & ROW(" & columnRange.row & ":" & columnNamesRowNumber + columnRange.Rows.Count + 1 & "))) * (" & columnLetter & columnRange.row & ":" & columnLetter & columnNamesRowNumber + columnRange.Rows.Count + 1 & ")) > 0) * 1) - 1"
```

Comment: What methods have you tried? Which was the nearest to being successful? Share that code with us and we can look to see where it can be improved.

Comment: Your question really needs more focus, as stated above.

Comment: I have researched for about a minute (if that) and came up with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883272/excel-2010-count-unique-values-only-in-a-subtotal-cell), is that what you're after?

Comment: What do you mean by *"even works when filtered"* you want it to only show results for the filter, or also for the excluded values from the filter

Comment: If you got Excel 365 you may benefit from [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/count-unique-values-only-in-filtered-dataset/m-p/2637785)

Comment: Instead of using a formula, since you are in vba, iterate the range and test if visible and then load a dictionary which will error if you try to put the same value in.  Then get the number of items in the dictionary.

Comment: I suggest to remove the comments.